# Reset sensor orientation

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have a sensor. This sensor returns a quaternion of the current orientation.
I've added reset orientation code, and it works perfectly:

```
void KeyPressedHandler()
{
    Quaternion CurrentQuat;
    var state = this.adapter.GetState();
    CurrentQuat = state.Value;

    if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.R))
    {
        Quaternion StartPosition;

        StartPosition.x = 0;
        StartPosition.y = 0;
        StartPosition.z = 0;
        StartPosition.w = 1;

        Offset = Quaternion.Inverse(CurrentQuat) * StartPosition;
    }
}

void Update()
{
    Quaternion CurrentQuat;

    var state = this.adapter.GetState();
    CurrentQuat = state.Value* Offset;
    transform.Rotation = CurrentQuat;
}
```

And I found the following problem. If I put the sensor on a horizontal table and rotate it around a vertical OZ axis, the model (in Unity) will also rotate around the OZ axis. Then I put the sensor on the side edge and if I rotate it around the OZ axis (OZ now in the horizontal plane), the model will rotate in a different axis. Not the OZ of the model... why? How do I preserve the axises on the sensor and model?

Comment: bad if not have info about the sensor...

Comment: Axises are binded until not reset in new position... if sensor put back to horizonal plane (OZ is vertical) and reset orientation, it's work again good, axises of sensor are match with model axises

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Should be follow:

```
CurrentQuat = Offset*state.Value;
```